# Get PowerShell .NET object from ISE or Console Host

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm wondering if it's possible to get a `System.Management.Automation.PowerShell` object from within a PowerShell console host, or Integrated Scripting Editor (ISE). I know that you can access the `Runspace` object by calling `$Host.Runspace`, but I need direct access to a `PowerShell` object (if it exists).

Would the only option be to create a new `PowerShell` object, and then call the code inside of that, or is there a way to access a pre-created `PowerShell` object using the `$Host` variable (or similar)?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell_members(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: May I inquire what you intend to do with the `PowerShell` instance?

Comment: I need to inspect the `PSDataStreams` property on it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [ScriptLogger blog post by Oisin](http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2009/08/19/PowerShell20AConfigurableAndFlexibleScriptLoggerModule) that uses PSDataStreams, I would say no. You need to create a PowerShell object `[powershell]::create()` and execute your script with the resulting object. Then, when you tap into the PSDataStreams collection, it will contain the various output from the executed script.

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is async execution, you probably want Powershell jobs.
Look into "start-job" and "invoke-command -asJob" if your goal is to spawn new shells/threads and execute code in them, then return data from that execution.  Those commands will generate a runspace- you can return data from them if you simply invoke a variable at the end of their scriptblock, then use:

```
$Var = get-job|receive-job
```

Powershell will handle runspace management brilliantly with minimal work- if you are managing runspaces manually, you are probably doing something the hard way.  Note that Invoke-command will allow you to execute these jobs on a remote machine- hugely powerful and efficient given the minimal amount of code you'll have to write to do it.